TwinCAT XAE Shell: "Creation of an Extension Failed" and Missing Target Browser in Simulink Tc Symbol Interface
I'm working with TwinCAT XAE Shell (TwinCAT 3) and trying to configure ADS communication. My TwinCAT system is in Run mode on a local target without any errors, but I am having trouble accessing the symbols in the Simulink Tc Symbol Interface Configuration window. The TwinCAT Target Browser section, where I should see the symbols, is not appearing at all, as shown in the images below:
this is the  normal view (what should I see according the BEKHOFF infosys)

and this is what I see In my PC:

Additionally, I keep getting the following warning:

'TwinCAT Target Browser': Creation of an extension failed.


Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Ensured TwinCAT is in Run mode.
Activated the configuration multiple times through TwinCAT and simulinkstrong text.
Rebuilt the PLC project.
Checked that the correct target is selected on local.
Restarted TwinCAT XAE Shell and my PC several times.
Tried running TwinCAT XAE Shell as Administrator.
Repair the TwinCAT3 with it installer.

Despite these efforts, the TwinCAT Target Browser section still does not appear, and I continue to see the "Creation of an extension failed" warning. As a result, I can't browse or select symbols in the Simulink Tc Symbol Interface.
Additional Info:
Using TwinCAT XAE Shell with Visual Studio 2019 integration.
The PLC project itself runs fine, and no major errors appear in the system logs.
Has anyone encountered this issue with TwinCAT XAE Shell or the Simulink Tc Symbol Interface? Any ideas on how to resolve the missing TwinCAT Target Browser section and the warning message?
Thanks in advance!

finally, I uninstalled it and then installed a new one and the problem has been solved.

From the top menu bar select
TwinCAT -> Target Browser -> Target Browser.
Once the target browser is open you can arrange the window how you like it.
The error you see regarding the extension, is something I have as well, yet I have not been able to find any blocking point in my daily use of Twincat.
